# Rotating image not working

Tags: c++, image-processing, openframeworks

I'm trying to rotate an image using openFrameworks, but I have a problem. My rotated image is red instead of its original color.

```
void testApp::setup(){
image.loadImage("abe2.jpg");
rotatedImage.allocate(image.width, image.height, OF_IMAGE_COLOR);

imageCenterX = image.getWidth() / 2;
imageCenterY = image.getHeight() / 2;
w = image.getWidth();
h = image.getHeight();
int degrees = 180;
float radians = (degrees*(PI / 180));

for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int index = image.getPixelsRef().getPixelIndex(x, y);

        int newX = (cos(radians) * (x - imageCenterX) - sin(radians) * (y - imageCenterY) + imageCenterX);
        int newY = (sin(radians) * (x - imageCenterX) + cos(radians) * (y - imageCenterY) + imageCenterY);

        int newIndex = rotatedImage.getPixelsRef().getPixelIndex(newX, newY);

        rotatedImage.getPixelsRef()[newIndex] = image.getPixelsRef()[index];
    }
}
rotatedImage.update();
}

 void testApp::update(){
 }

void testApp::draw(){
image.draw(0,0);
rotatedImage.draw(0,400);
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the red thing reminds me instinctively of failing to realize the RGB separation of planes and accidentally only operating on one of them. Not familiar with OFW though, so I won't be of much help I bet

Comment: And your rotation operation could be the result of accidentally flipping indices. Check to make sure that every use of an index (x,y,etc) is exactly the one you mean

Comment: Just realised i used minus instead of plus when calculating newY. Fixed it and rotating works now. Only the color issue is a problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image has three color components (Red, Green, Blue), you need to transform all three of those. The following should do the trick:

```
rotatedImage.getPixelsRef()[newIndex] = image.getPixelsRef()[index];
rotatedImage.getPixelsRef()[newIndex+1] = image.getPixelsRef()[index+1];
rotatedImage.getPixelsRef()[newIndex+2] = image.getPixelsRef()[index+2];
```